# Flask SQL-Alchemy query is returning null for data that exists in my database. What could be the cause

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, mysql-workbench, flask-sqlalchemy

My python program is meant to query my MySQL database for a record. The record exists in the database and contains data but the program returns null values. The table that gets queried is titled **Market**. In that table there is a column titled **market_cap** and a column titled **volume**. When I use MySQLWorkbench to query my database, the result shows that there is data in the columns. However, the program receives null.

Attached are two images (links, because I need to earn 10 reputation points to embed images in a post):

1. [MySql database column image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaou2.jpg)
   shows a view of the column in my database that is having issues.
   From the image, you can see that the data I need exists in my database.
2. [Code with results from Pycharm debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Ur7.jpg)
   Before running the debugger, I set a breakpoint right after the line where
   the code queries the database for an object. Image two shows the output I
   received when the code queried the database.

   3. [Screenshot of the Market Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rdkc.jpg)
   4. [Screenshot of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQhHc.jpg) I found out that converting the market cap(market_cap) before adding it to the dictionary(price_map) returns the correct value. You can see it in line 138.

What could cause existent data in a record to be returned as null?

```
import logging
from flask_restful import Resource
from api.resources.util.date_util import pretty_date_to_epoch, 
epoch_to_pretty_date
from common.decorators import log_exception
from db.models import db, Market
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def map_date_to_price():
    buy_date_list = ["2015-01-01", "2015-02-01", "2015-03-01"]
    sell_date_list = ["2014-12-19", "2014-01-10", "2015-01-20",
                      "2016-01-10"]
    date_list = buy_date_list + sell_date_list    
    market_list = []
    price_map = {}
    for day in date_list:
        market_list.append(db.session.query(Market).
        filter(Market.pretty_date == day).first())
    for market in market_list:
        price_map[market.pretty_date] = market.market_cap

    return price_map
```

Comment: What is `pretty_date`, datetime, varchar, something else?

Comment: Do you mean null values, or no results? Try the query by hand. I assume it'd look like `select * from market where pretty_date = '2015-01-01';`

Comment: @DaveW.Smith I mean null values, as shown in image 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5Ur7.jpg . Image 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oaou2.jpg  shows the output when I try the query by hand.

Comment: @Boris It's a string.

Comment: Can we see the market model? Did you insert the data manually or through the application?

Comment: @TimThompson a screenshot of the market model has been added as (3.) above. The data in the Market table was inserted through the application.

Comment: I have solved it. I appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The two fields that are (apparently) being retrieved as null are both `db.Numeric`. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/type_basics.html notes that these are, by default, backed up by a `decimal.Decimal` object, which I'll bet can't be converted to JSON, so what comes back form `Market.__repr__()` will show them as `null`.

I would try adding `asdecimal=False` to the two `db.Numeric()` calls in `Market`.

Comment: I need both of them to store Decimals. Thanks.

Comment: Then you'll need to do something else for those fields in `__repr__()`.